# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2? working well occasionally or have like a this problem

Tags: java

What has this code a problem?? if I changed an original file to new, worked well sometimes but not always. Plz let me know how to fix it. thx.

```
public void loadMovie() throws IOException {

    File infile = new File("./res/movies.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(infile);

    while (input.hasNext()) {

        String movieData = input.nextLine();

        String[] args = movieData.split(",");

        int duration = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        String title = args[1];

        movieList.add(new Movie(duration, title, year));
    }

    input.close();

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>     at
>   sait.mms.managers.MovieManagementSystem.loadMovie(MovieManagementSystem.java:137)
>     at sait.mms.application.AppDriver.main(AppDriver.java:21)

Comment: Without knowing what the data in `movieData` looks like, it is impossible to say whether there would more m\than comma in the data.  If there is only one comma then the array would consist of only two elements [0] & [1]

Comment: movie.txt has a format like

141,Wonder Woman,2017

Comment: well some of you data is **not** like that - put in a array length check

Comment: `if (args.length < 3) {
   System.out.println("My data is stuffed");
   continue;
  }`

Comment: I already checked and no problem on a data file, and also I used to change the file to new in order to find a problem, but same error. 
thx for reply

Comment: @JayXD *"no problem on a data file"* If there was no problem in the data file, then you wouldn't get that error. You can only get that error if there is a line without 2 commas, or if there is no text after the second comma. Look again!